# failed to connect Java Project with MySQL Workbench (TIMEZONE error)

Tags: java, sql

i have homework, and i need use mysql and java.
i need acces to my table on mysql workbench, the table employeee,
i download the driver and do every thing right,
but i get error of :

> The server time zone value '???? ???? ???????' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the `serverTimezone` configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

if its relevant this is my code.

```
   import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Connection myConn = null;
    try {
        myConn =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee", 
"root", "root");

        //create statement
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        if (myConn !=null) {
            System.out.println("connection succsesful");
            //excute sql query
            ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from project");

            //process the result set
            while(myRs.next()) {
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("DNUM") + "," + myRs.getString("PNUMBER"));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("connection failed");
        exc.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the first argument to `DriverManager.getConnection` from `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee"` to `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee?serverTimezone=UTC`.

If you don't want to use UTC, substitute `UTC` for the timezone you want the database to record/display times in.

Comment: i try this and its not work.

Answer (score 1):

So in the end, I downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.48 driver and now its work well.

Comment: This is the answer section, you shouldn't ask/include any questions here....

Comment: This is answer section.

Answer (score -1):

Your next question - how i can check if he input Incorrect query on sql language?
I think if your sql query syntax is **wrong**, you will receive **MySQLSyntaxErrorException**.
And you can check **ResultSet** is empty.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(yourQuery);
if(rs.next()==false)
 System.out.println("ResultSet is empty");
else{
 while(rs.next()){
  //get data from table
 }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect: it will skip the first row, you would need to use `do-while` instead. Also this doesn't answer the question that was asked. You also shouldn't use comparisons like `rs.next() == false`, use `!rs.next()` or invert the if statement.